# LSPCI detects two 3D display vga

Tags: debian, nvidia, graphics, remote-desktop

I'm running debian 11 (Bullseye) with AMD CPU (without iGPU) + NVIDIA GT1030. Initially the debian did not recognize the gpu driver (which is just my guess) because the screen was all black until I added `nomodeset` in the GRU parameter. Then I installed linux nvidia driver that supports GT1030.

The problem is that under the command `$ lspci -nn | egrep -i "3d|display|vga"` I find two vga's:

```
02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller [1022:43d5] (rev 01)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] [10de:1d01] (rev a1)
```

and I'm not sure which one is in use. My goal is to strictly use GT1030 for any graphical task/load, particularly for VNC remote control.

On a side note, I noticed that, on Windows, whenever the graphics card detects no output signal, it automatically turns itself off. For example, I set up a teamviewer in my machines to record a lecture with a remote device (my phone) later with Nvidia shadowplay, but the GPU went off as soon as I left the room with the monitor turned off. How to prevent such trouble, by forcing the GPU on stand-by mode at all time?

Answer (score 1):

Your `lspci` command is matching two devices, one of which *isn’t* a GPU:

```
02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 400 Series Chipset USB 3.1 XHCI Controller [1022:43d5] (rev 01)
```

This is a USB controller. It matches because its device id, 43d5, includes the “3d” string.

Your system is using its NVIDIA GPU.

Comment: That was really stupid of me. Thank you